# Why templateUrl change compilation behavior?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does templateUrl change the compilation behavior? If you comment out line 7 you can see 44.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive('something', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            terminal: true,
            //templateUrl: 'select.html'
            template: '<span ng-bind="name"></span>'
        }
    }]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

select.html contain same html code: `<span ng-bind="name"></span>`

see plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lmU3JW?p=preview

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you are asking?

Comment: If we use a templateUrl instead template it's works pretty well, i can't understand difference.

Comment: `template` doesn't work because of the `terminal` condition - which means no other directives will be executes (which includes also `$compile`ation of the template. - templateUrl is working because the template is loaded **asyncron**. This might be a bug or a feature - not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

remove the base-href - no need in the plunker

```
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

also don't use number for identifier. '44' is a bad property name
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTvl7rKAHWhhKMsL1mkt?p=preview)